# Execute tasks simultaneously in parallel in C# .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, parallel-processing, simultaneous

I am trying to execute an array of tasks at exactly the same time, to the nanosecond. Is this possible?

It seems like the more tasks I add, the greater the range of inaccuracy - which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong.

Is there a best practice for this?

Here is my code with the results I am getting:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] iterations = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
        Func<Task<DateTime>>[] delegates = new Func<Task<DateTime>>[iterations.Length];

        foreach (int i in iterations)
        {
            async Task<DateTime> GetTime()
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return DateTime.Now;
            }

            delegates[Array.IndexOf(iterations, i)] = GetTime;
        }

        Task<DateTime>[] tasks = delegates
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(async task => await task())
            .ToArray();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        DateTime[] dateTimes = tasks
            .Select(l => l.Result)
            .ToArray();

        foreach (DateTime dateTime in dateTimes)
            Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));
        Console.WriteLine("Range: " + (dateTimes.Max() - dateTimes.Min()).TotalMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

My average result for 100 iterations:

> Range: 7.6709

Comment: What is the practical use case for ensuring that tasks run at the same time, down to the nanosecond? What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: Collecting time-sensitive data.

Comment: Collecting what time sensitive data? Again: what practical problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm quite sure that my real world problems are unnecessary here. I am looking for an objective review of my question. Objectively, I am trying to reduce the range to absolute 0.

Comment: They're quite necessary. The [help page for Stack Overflow says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". It's not clear what part of this is practical. It would also guide answers, because you're doing something very unusual and it's not clear why.

Comment: If you want to do something like this, you need to do it at the hardware level, and certainly not in a garbage collected environment.  In a previous lifetime, we did this in a control system that used two isolated processors that shared timing and a controlled access inter-processor bus - all programmed in C and C++.  Even then, it was at the millisecond level.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive feedback @Flydog57 - that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not even sure garbage-collection and JIT compilation are even in the running here in terms of real-time performance. Even running on bare-metal x86/x64 isn't going to work because you only have 4 or 8 processors. I think you're going to need some kind of specialized microchip or FPGA that specializes in real-time synchronization. 1ns is equivalent to 1Ghz, so you're right down to transistor-level here.

Comment: Now, that all said, you can get reasonable determinism for short periods of time if you are careful with allocations, use the new (4.0 era) GC features to inhibit collections and your machine is dedicated to the task at hand. It's far from hard real time, but it's somewhat close to soft real time

Comment: @Flydog57, Would be interesting to see how to implement this, and what impact the GC has on latency.

Comment: Take a look at `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion`. It allows you to mark a region of code that should run without GC interruption (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion. Then do all the things you'd do in embedded code like pre-allocate as much stuff as you can (and perhaps use some buffer management)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to execute an array of tasks at exactly the same time, to the nanosecond. Is this possible?

No. This is not possible on any operating system that uses preemptive scheduling, such as Windows or Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.